# Change CSS element that comes after another

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to hover in `a.bio` change the background `.pic` to green.

I tried some ways, but it did not work out.

I did not understand the logic of `~`  and how even to make it work.

**CODE**

```css
.executivo .pic::after {
  background-color: #00845b;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.equipe a.bio:hover ~ .pic::after {
  opacity: 0.35;
}
.executivo .pic {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  position: relative;
}
.executivo .pic img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="executivo">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="<?php echo $pic; ?>" alt="<?php echo $nome; ?>" />
  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <h3><?php echo $nome; ?></h3>
  </div>

  <a class="bio" href="#">Bio+</a>

</div>
```

Comment: you could do so if the image is placed after the link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move your `a.bio` in your HTML, because `~` is a sibling selector (however less strict than the `+`),  and use `position` to stay as it was before moving the HTML:

#### Snippet

```css
.executivo .pic::after {
  background-color: #00845b;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.executivo {
  position: relative;
}
.executivo a.bio {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px
}
.executivo a.bio:hover ~ .pic img {
  opacity: 0.35;
}
.executivo .pic {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  position: relative;
}
.executivo .pic img {
  display: block;
  max-width:100% /*demo*/
}
```

```html
<div class="executivo">
  <a class="bio" href="#">Bio+</a>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" alt="alt text" />
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h3>title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the link .bio have to stay down.

Comment: @MarcoRiesco you could position it with css, but I think this is the only way.

Comment: With a.bio below, not be possible?

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look, I use `position`, thats the only option if you want to have `.bio` below the `img`

Comment: Thank you for this alternative, I believe is the only option to use only css.

Answer (score -1):

Nex element selector is

```
+
```

And direct decedent is

```
>
```

in css.

Does this help you answer your question?

Comment: You will not be able to use css to hover another element in this way.

Comment: .bio:hover > .pic but you should change the html order.

Comment: Jquery can do this yes - are you saying you want jquery then not css?

Comment: no no, i want use pure css, but if not way I use jquery, patience.